# Sanitizing some SQL queries

Tags: php, sql

What would be the easiest and most effective way to sanitize this:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `admin` " 
."WHERE `username`=' ".$_POST["username"]."' " 
."AND `passcode`=' ".$_POST["password"]."' "
```

Also, I am learning PHP so if you could please provide explanations, tips, suggestions, or more ways to clean up stuff to prevent SQL injections that would be most appreciated

Comment: Use PDO or mysqli and look into prepared statements for either. They both have sanitizing options that will be well documented.

Comment: use  mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Aside from sanitizing the query, you should consider hashing and salting your passwords rather than storing them in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use $mysqli `prepared statements` - here is an example from the PHP site:

Explanation (see the bottom for an example using your code):

You replace the variables in the query with `?` marks, and then `bind` the variables in at a later time.

```
$city = "Amersfoort";

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

---

**Example using your code:**

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `admin` " 
."WHERE `username`= ? AND passcode = ?";


/* create a prepared statement */
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q)) {

        /* bind parameters for markers */
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

        /* execute query */
        $stmt->execute();

        /* bind result variables */
        $stmt->bind_result($district);

        /* fetch value */
        $stmt->fetch();  // This can also be while($stmt->fetch()){ Code here }

        printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

        /* close statement */
        $stmt->close();
    }

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
```

Comment: I believe that example code you tried to make sucks lol. Also I would be using PDO mysqli isnt really as good.

Comment: "Example using your code" *throws $q= line at the top and does nothing else* Oh yea look at me im such a troll

Comment: Whatever this topic is dead anyways no point in continuing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really had to know it would be something like:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `admin` " 
."WHERE `username`=' ".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"])."' " 
."AND `passcode`=' ".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"])."' "
```

But as the others said, you should be using most likely PDO or mysqli because all mysql_ commands are deprecated.